# how can I flush all redis nodes through predis?

Tags: redis, predis

I am trying to test my cache was implemented with redis clustering (cluster by server not client).
I have to flush redis every time I run a unit test.
when I try to run flushdb command I got this error:
Cannot use 'FLUSHDB' with redis-cluster.
it seems that I can run flushdb command in cluster mode only when I set the slot but I do not know how to do it. (I have overridden redis wrapper of laravel so laravel is not the case If you learn me how to use predis I can adopt it with laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting by pattern:

```
redis-cli --raw keys "$PATTERN" | xargs redis-cli del
```

for example:

```
redis-cli KEYS "prefix:*" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

For deleting all keys from one db:

```
redis-cli flushdb
```

For deleting all keys from all dbs:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

For cluster mode you need to use this bash script:
https://gist.github.com/yaud/85e0382d26c189bdf84f0297cd54f479
to remove all nodes from master nodes (slave nodes will be synced)